# Get the row and column of the cell, where xlwings UDF was called?

Tags: python, excel, user-defined-functions, xlwings

I am using the xlwings library and I am creating custom UDF functions.

```
@xw.func
def hello(name):
    return f"Hello {name}!{os.getcwd()}"
```

How can I get the row and the column of the cell where the function is called?

To clarify, I want to access the row and the column inside the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `caller` argument, see: https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/udfs.html#the-caller-argument

```py
@xw.func
def hello(name, caller):
    # caller is an xlwings range object
    row, col = caller.row, caller.column
    return f"Hello {name}!{os.getcwd()}"
```